# Android - questions about listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I'm new to programming and am making a test project in android, although I already have some practice. But now I have some roadblocks (perhaps some more will appear later) that I can't seem to unblock. Here are my first 2 questions for anyone that can answer:

In the same activity and using the same listview, is it possible to click in one view, and get the listview filled with an array of information that it's descended from the chosen view? I'm using SQLite in a helper activity. I can pass the data from an activity to another activity using "Intent", but I'm unable to in the same activity.

In making an arrayAdapter, and using ViewHolder, is it possible to get the array images to be attributed to different resource.id´s? I have tried to concatenate the R.id´s with an holder.X.setText() (that way the images would be distributed according to the data present in that holder) but I'm unable to.

Here is the adapter class

```
public class PecasAdaptador extends ArrayAdapter<Peca> {

private final Context context;
private final Peca[] values;

static class ViewHolder {

    public TextView versao;
    public TextView preco;
    public TextView potencia;
    public ImageView foto;
}

public PecasAdaptador(Context context, Peca[] values) {
    super(context, -1, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.peca, null);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.versao = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.versao);
    viewHolder.potencia = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.potencia);
    viewHolder.preco = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.novorobot5);
    rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    holder.versao.setText(values[position].getVersao());
    holder.potencia.setText(Aplicacao.recursos.getQuantityString(R.plurals.potencia, values[position].getPotencia()));
    holder.preco.setText(Aplicacao.recursos.getQuantityString(R.plurals.preco, values[position].getPreco()));
    holder.foto.setImageResource(values[position].getFoto());
    return rowView;
}
```

}

Here is the activity class

```
public class NovoRobotActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

PecasHelper helper = new PecasHelper(this);
String nometipo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_novo_robot);
    Button NovaPeca = (Button) findViewById(R.id.novorobot3);
    final ArrayAdapter tipos = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, helper.listaTipos());
    final PecasAdaptador versoes = new PecasAdaptador(this, helper.listaVersoes(nometipo));
    final ListView listapecas = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
    NovaPeca.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listapecas.setAdapter(tipos);
            listapecas.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> tipos, View view, int i, long l) {
                   TextView t = (TextView) view;
                   nometipo = t.getText().toString();
                   listapecas.setAdapter(versoes);
               }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: You say "roadblocks" but you have failed to post the code you tried and where you think it went wrong. Suggest checking [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You shouldn't set the adapter or the item click listener within the button click on listener. Also, switching adapters when you click on an item seems like a strange design

Comment: @ cricket_007 I must set the adapter within the button, because i want the button to start the listview. Also, i dont want to change the activiy, because i want to see the images being inserted in the activity outside the listview.

Comment: @ cricket_007 But i may have wrong ideas about it. I apreciate if you could help me.

Comment: I have edited first post to add an updated activity. But it still doesnt work. The listview just goes blank when i click any item.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use ArrayAdapter for

> RecyclerView or ListView

You have to change in array or array list which you are passing to adapter constructor.

So, when you click on list item update the array list which you are passing to adapter and after that just called `adaptername.notifydatasetchanged()` method in your activity.

This will update your adapter with new list by just clicking on item of list view.